# Replacing a string with 2 other strings separatly

Tags: c++, string, replace, find

I was looking for replacing a character in a string with a character in another string comparing to another string.
Well, hard to describe this, a code would be better :

```
std::string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
std::string keyboard = "AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBNazertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn";

std::string change(std::string str)
{
    for (short i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return str;
}
```

Well, I don't think it is understandable, so what I try to do is :

1. Find (maybe Find() ?) the letter in str and get the i-variable in alphabet.
2. With the i-variable  want to get the pos and then get the letter in the keyboard string.

Hope you understand what I mean, and thank you.

I though about replace(), find() and swap(), but didn't work, I maybe did something wrong.
Thank you in advance !

EDIT : Well, I was sure you won't understand anything, imagine str = "Hello", I want to replace H per Y (alphabet = H -> keyboard = I)? (alphabet get the position of the H in the alphabet string, we memorise this position in i, and we keyboard[i]), this is what I want to do.

Comment: take a look at `std::transform`, and no, I didn't really understand what you're trying to do. Maybe post a simple example. Are you trying to map between different keyboard layouts?

Comment: Apart from the code (which does little-to-nothing as far as we can tell, since `str` is unknown and `keyboard` isn't used *at all*), perhaps show use a before/after version of an input/output string as it relates to your two alphabet and keyboard strings. As-written your question is difficult to read, and at-best-guessable to answer. Something tells me the words "map" and "transform" belong somewhere in this question.

Comment: Your code is more confusing than your question. If you can't even explain it, how can you program it?

Comment: So, you are saying that `str = "Hello"` will be changed to `Itssg'. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose

```
template <typename InputIterator,
          typename BidirIterator,
          typename ForwardIterator>
InputIterator substitute( InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                          BidirIterator key_first, BidirIterator key_last,
                          ForwardIterator val_first )
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        auto&& ref = *first;
        auto i = std::lower_bound( key_first, key_last, ref );

        if (i == key_last || *i != ref)
            return first;

        ref = *std::next(val_first, std::distance(key_first, i));
    }

    return last;
}
```

This assumes that `[key_first, key_last)` is sorted and that `val_first` refers to a range that is at least as long as `[key_first, key_last)`. 
[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1e777f785a5ed51).

The idea is that we iterate through all elements of a range using iterators whose type is to be determined - i.e. we can use both `char const[]`s and `std::vector<char>`s. We pick the current element and use a binary search to find that element within the key set. Then we use the offset to access the substitution counterpart in the value set, and assign that to our original element.

We use `lower_bound` to do the binary search. It doesn't itself constitute one, so we have to apply some checks to the return value to ensure the iterator refers to the correct value. If we couldn't find the key then the iterator to the first non-working element is returned. (That can be the past-the-end iterator.)

The avove is a general method that works for arbitrary key/value sets: For alphabetic shuffling there are (platform dependent) methods using lookup tables. Rustically this could look like this:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void substitute( InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 char const* values )
{
    char lookup[UCHAR_MAX+1];
    for (int c = 0; c != sizeof lookup; ++c)
        if (std::isupper(c))
            lookup[c] = values[c - 'A'];
        else if (std::islower(c))
            lookup[c] = values[c - 'a' + 26];
        else
            lookup[c] = c;

    // Further adjustments to the table can be made here

    std::transform( first, last, first,
                     [&] (unsigned char c) {return lookup[c];} );
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fdee6ccd1425df2). It depends on stuff that normal character sets should easily suffice. The table can also be created elsewhere and passed to transform via the unwrapped one-liner. This is especially efficient for large string transformations as no branching is necessary in the implicit loop in `transform`.

Comment: If I wanted to add, on top of that, for exemple the "!", what should I do ? And at the moment, what method is faster ? Thank you again

Comment: @NorthernLight In that case I'd just use the first method.

Comment: @Columbo: No, your new version assumes A-Z and a-z are contiguous and in order. Why not a constant-time lookup table, as I've suggested?

Comment: Ok. Apparently, only ASCII character are supported, any idea for é/è/ê/ù/ñ/ì... ? which doesn't make the program run

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because a lookup table doesn't necessarily bring you any performance boost, but is surely not as shortly implemented.

Comment: @Columbo: Except WhozCraig's implementation is noticeably shorter than yours, and yes, there's quite an obvious performance boost.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I want to see the shorter one that is as generic and uses a lookup table.

Comment: @Columbo: You've fallen into the trap of favouring re-usability over _every_ other concern and, as a consequence, your code is harder to read, longer, and algorithmically slower. The OP doesn't need this to be generic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The code needs some form of re-usability, but I am indeed known to exaggerate in that respect. I'm gonna add a lookup-table based approach without templates, but you didn't answer my (implicit) question.

Comment: @Columbo: Yes I did; implicitly. :) Don't worry, I used to do that too. It does not need this re-usability; that's a requirement that you've invented out of thin air. If it came for free or even cheaply, then fine... but it clearly doesn't here as evidenced by simply comparing your solution to WhozCraig's.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I somehow got something. It's not portable and it's definitely not that readable. ;)

Comment: @Columbo: And now you're using `std::toupper`, for which you told off another answerer due to UB!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Firstly I'm not using `toupper`, secondly `c` is always in a range representable by `unsigned char`. The other answer passed a `char` to `isupper`, which is potentially signed.

Comment: @Columbo: Fair points.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I admit that it would be easier by just using a premade hand-written table, but I feel that that's kinda error-prone.

Comment: @Columbo: How is it more error-prone? You have to provide the input somehow, even in your version.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean the generation of the lookup table inside with all its 256 entries, not the scrambled one passed. Don't you think it would be unduly tedious to create a string with 256 entries, each of which is precisely reflecting the value it should at the corresponding position?

Comment: @Columbo: I don't understand what alternative you propose. That's necessary in your version, too, isn't it? Or is the computer program supposed to magically divine the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to replace every char in your string with a char from keyboard string using original char's position in alphabet?

I would consider using a map alphabet char to keyboard char. Then iterate through string and replace its characters.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::map<char, char> alphabetToKeyboard;
    alphabetToKeyboard['A'] = 'A';
    alphabetToKeyboard['B'] = 'Z';
    alphabetToKeyboard['C'] = 'E';

    std::string str = "ABC";

    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [&alphabetToKeyboard](char c) {
        return alphabetToKeyboard[c];
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ++1: Not a bad solution. Probably nice and fast, too. Since you don't have that many possible inputs on each iteration, you might consider just using a run of the mill array to get constant-time lookup.

Comment: Regarding how to do this with a small-size-domain like `char` using an index array lookup as Lightness suggested, [see one such example here](http://ideone.com/269RaR). Obviously this is something you would prepare ahead of time if there were many invokes of `change()`. For a single-shot call or large-string invokes, the constant prep-time becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That'd make a good answer, btw...

Comment: @WhozCraig, this one has a sweet move with the supporting array size : )

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I agree, first thing to optimize this is to use an array for const time access. I just was not sure if the solution should be able to be scaled to wchar (usually it should be if we're talking about production code).

Comment: @d453: Perhaps. Although `wchar_t` is not particularly useful for _real_ Unicode support.